# How to use icon from bootstrap locally

Tags: html, css

In this case

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I can see the icon when use this reference:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
    <span>Cancel upload</span>
</button>
```

But if I download the file locally ([from this link](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)), it does not work, I cannot see the icon anymore:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyFolder/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the Glyphicon font's files and place them in the `fonts` folder besides the `css` folder:

```
your_site_root/
    css/
        bootstrap.min.css
    fonts/
        glyphicons-halflings*.*
```

I suggest you to download the Bootstrap pack from the [official site](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download). The distribution ZIP file will contain all files you will need to build a site with Bootstrap, including the CSS, JS and font files.